# Не вижу логов в результате выполнения приложения с log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Написал код взираясь на документацию с http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html.

package javaapplication2;

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class App {
    private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger("Hello World");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Hello World");
    }

}
```

я так понимаю оно как результат выполения приложения должо что то показать, но я вижу только это:

> run: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5
> seconds)

что я не так делаю? или где я могу посмотреть выход консоли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Его еще и настроить надо, аппендер указать
Можно [здесь](http://skipy.ru/useful/logging.html) почитать